# Flatten pandas DataFrame without pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a MultiIndex pandas DataFrame after calling `groupby`, and need to flatten it in a fashion [similar to flattening a pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576795/flatten-dataframe-with-multi-index-columns).  Most of the analysis is already built around the grouped object, so would prefer to not have to refactor into a pivot table.

Consider some dummy data,

```
dummy_data = pd.DataFrame({'Ccy' : ['EUR', 'EUR', 'CAD', 'CAD', 'EUR', 'EUR', 'CAD', 'EUR'],
                  'Venue' : ['BAML']*5 + ['BARX']*3,
                  'Price': np.abs(np.random.randn(8)),
                  'volume': np.abs(10*np.random.randn(8))
                   }, 
                  index = pd.date_range('7/19/2017', periods=8))

dummy_data.index.name = "datetime"
print dummy_data


>>>            Ccy     Price Venue     volume
datetime                                  
2017-07-19  EUR  1.338521  BAML  11.227553
2017-07-20  EUR  0.882715  BAML   0.307711
2017-07-21  CAD  0.977815  BAML  14.196170
2017-07-22  CAD  1.262272  BAML   0.055213
2017-07-23  EUR  0.752433  BAML   5.315777
2017-07-24  EUR  0.699008  BARX   2.299045
2017-07-25  CAD  1.625567  BARX   6.474822
2017-07-26  EUR  2.122562  BARX   5.026135
```

The goal is to group data by `Ccy` and `Venue`, apply a `filter` operation to each subgroup, and then flatten the groups back into the format of this original frame.  Consider a simple filter that retains rows where `price > 0.8`

```
dummy_data.groupby(['Ccy', 'Venue']).apply(lambda x: x[x['Price'] > 0.8])

>>>                      Ccy     Price Venue     volume
Ccy Venue datetime                                  
CAD BAML  2017-07-21  CAD  0.977815  BAML  14.196170
          2017-07-22  CAD  1.262272  BAML   0.055213
    BARX  2017-07-25  CAD  1.625567  BARX   6.474822
EUR BAML  2017-07-19  EUR  1.338521  BAML  11.227553
          2017-07-20  EUR  0.882715  BAML   0.307711
    BARX  2017-07-26  EUR  2.122562  BARX   5.026135
```

All I need now is to fill-in/flatten the `Ccy` and `Venue` columns such that

```
Ccy Venue datetime                                  
CAD BAML  2017-07-21  ...                       CAD BAML 2017-07-21  ...
          2017-07-22  ...                       CAD BAML 2017-07-22  ... 
    BARX  2017-07-25  ...    ---> BECOMES --->  CAD BARX 2017-07-25 ...
EUR BAML  2017-07-19  ...                       EUR BAML 2017-07-19 ... 
          2017-07-20  ...                       EUR BAML 2017-07-20  ...
```

*I need to do this because we have a range of plotting utilities that aren't flexible enough to handle grouped data*.  Shouldn't there be an `ungroup()` or `flatten()` method that is reciprocal to the `groupby()` operation?

**Note:** the trivial filter in this example could have been applied to the ungrouped data.  In reality, my filter is more complex and only makes sense on subgroups.

---

**Solution Attempts** (Attempts 1 and 2 from [pivot table solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576795/flatten-dataframe-with-multi-index-columns))

**Attempt 1**: `melt` method loses the `datetime` index.

```
    print dummy_data.groupby(['Ccy', 'Venue']).apply(lambda x: x[x['Price'] > 0.8]).melt()

>>>   variable      value
0       Ccy        CAD
1       Ccy        CAD
2       Ccy        CAD
3       Ccy        EUR
4       Ccy        EUR
5       Ccy        EUR
6     Price   0.977815
7     Price    1.26227
8     Price    1.62557
9     Price    1.33852
```

**Attempt 2:** the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576795/flatten-dataframe-with-multi-index-columns) leads to a `KeyError`

```
dummy_data.groupby(['Ccy', 'Venue']).apply(lambda x: x[x['Price'] > 0.8]).unstack().reset_index().drop('level_0', axis=1)
```

> KeyError: 'level_0'

**Attempt 3:** `reset_index()` leads to ValueError

```
dummy_data.groupby(['Ccy', 'Venue']).apply(lambda x: x[x['Price'] > 0.8]).reset_index()
```

> ValueError: cannot insert Venue, already exists

**Attempt 4:**  `as_index=False` (without `group_keys` keyword)

```
out = dummy_data.groupby(['Ccy', 'Venue'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x[x['Price'] > 0.8])
print out
print out.index

              Ccy     Price Venue     volume
  datetime                                  
0 2017-07-21  CAD  0.977815  BAML  14.196170
  2017-07-22  CAD  1.262272  BAML   0.055213
1 2017-07-25  CAD  1.625567  BARX   6.474822
2 2017-07-19  EUR  1.338521  BAML  11.227553
  2017-07-20  EUR  0.882715  BAML   0.307711
3 2017-07-26  EUR  2.122562  BARX   5.026135
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3], [2017-07-19 00:00:00, 2017-07-20 00:00:00, 2017-07-21 00:00:00, 2017-07-22 00:00:00, 2017-07-25 00:00:00, 2017-07-26 00:00:00]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 5]],
           names=[None, u'datetime'])
```

This gets me very close, but this object is still `MultiIndexed`.  How can we just get the datetime index back?

Comment: I think you need reset_index after your pivot

Comment: Check out attempt 3 in my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you want:

```
dummy_data.groupby(['Ccy', 'Venue'], group_keys=False)\
          .apply(lambda x: x[x['Price'] > 0.8])
```

Comment: Ahh slick thank you.  Wasn't aware of this magic keyword.  Any reason that this solution is preferable to COLDSPEED's suggestion?  Both do the same thing more or less.  Can you update answe rto have the .apply() filter just for completeness

Comment: @AdamHughes Speed... this solution is a few ticks faster because the index is inherently dropped.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer for (presumed) speed increase and winning code golf.  Appreciate both solutions

Comment: Not really. It just seemed cleaner to do it up front, rather than after (e.g. if  you are doing multiple operations on the `groupby()`, then you only do this once). I did not know the  magic word until just now, but seems handy :)

Comment: Just noticed that this works without the `as_index` keyword.  Should we drop it and only retain `group_keys` in accepted answer?

Comment: @AdamHughes Edited. Also, deleted my answer, this is miles better.