# How to reformat this pandas multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

How to turn:
[Original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM9Cr.png)

into this:
[Wanted dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAygW.png)

(sorry I don't know how to paste excel table here.)

Been messing around with pandas stack, pivot_table, melt, but can't seem to make it work. I need some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: `print(df.to_dict())` for the above sample dataframe and paste it in the question for users to replicate the dataframe into their systems

Comment: does this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576795/flatten-dataframe-with-multi-index-columns?

Comment: just upload your excel file to somewhere and give us the link then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created excel for the shown screenshot of the [sheetfile](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T7xXeSzdq-7AIGmNgsadA2r-8ltY3cVY8Q9ApsplgGs/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

---

```
df = pd.read_excel('PythonExport.xlsx', 
                   header=[0,1,2],index_col=[0,1],
                 )
```

---

**df:**

[image]

---

```
x = df.T.swaplevel(0,1).T.stack().stack().reset_index()
x.columns = ['repeat','condition','day','type','length','weight']
x = x.fillna(0)
```

---

**x:**

[image]