# Flatten multiindex dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I've got a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
                                  M
AAL XXX                 1.244000e+09
    YYY                 9.036011e+00
    ZZZ                 0.000000e+00
    WWW                 1.124000e+09
    UUU                -2.220000e+08
...                                           ...
XPO XXX                -3.221000e+06
    YYY                 2.450590e+08
    ZZZ                 1.770200e+07
    III                 1.770200e+07
    NNN                 2.719070e+08
```

With index 0 being AAL, ... and XPO. There are also some rows in index 1 that differ from index 0 to index 0. For example feature UUU is present only in AAL while III is present only in XPO. They both contain feature XXX, YYY and ZZZ though.

I want the desired output to be:

```
Index_0_Orignal XXX         YYY          ZZZ          WWW          UUU ...       III          NNN
AAL             1.244000e+0 9.036011e+00 0.000000e+00 1.124000e+09 -2.220000e+08 
XPO             -3.221000e  2.450590e+08 1.770200e+07                            1.770200e+07 2.719070e+08
```

Trying the solutions posted in the marked duplicate [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27576795/flatten-dataframe-with-multi-index-columns) does not work and yields a ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unstack`:

```
>>> df.unstack(level=1).droplevel(0,1)
```

Comment: this unfortunately does not work and yields a ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Can you update your post to provide a sample of your data using `df.head(10).to_dict()`?